# Boot command in openwrt

Tags: tcp, openwrt

I am using the luci interface to put the command at startup, but as it emits output I do not know if it is recommended to put >> /dev/null

```
# Put your custom commands here that should be executed once
# the system init finished. By default this file does nothing.

#rtl_tcp -a 192.168.1.1
# or
#rtl_tcp -a 192.168.1.1 >> /dev/null

exit 0
```

Comment: It would not hurt to redirect. Unless, one has connected a serial console, there is no way to see the outputs. You can do `rtf_tcp -a 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: In UNIX and Linux, streams are numbered as STDIN = 0, STDOUT = 1 and STDERR = 2. So, `2>&1` effectively redirecting the STDERR to STDOUT. In your case STDERR is effectively redirected to `/dev/null`